# How to use AmazonSQS listener with two accounts

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have application with two worker classes. I want them to pull from AWS SQS ,but from two different accounts.
I am using @SQSListener to achive this. I am having trouble to set the right AmazonSQS client for each queue.Tried to use custom destionationResolver but again it cannot access the right amazonSQS client bean. 
I'm using AmazonSQSAsync maybe this is part of the problem. Whit the custom destination resolver i am getting access denied  for one of the queues. 
My config code:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    @Primary
    public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQS() {

        AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsyncClient = new AmazonSQSAsyncClient(new AWSCredentialsProvider() {
            public void refresh() {}

            public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
                return new AWSCredentials() {
                    public String getAWSSecretKey() {return secretKey;}

                    public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {return accessKey;}
                };
            }
        });

        QueueBufferConfig config = new QueueBufferConfig();
        config.setMaxBatchOpenMs(maxBatchOpenMs);
        config.setMaxBatchSize(maxBatchSize);

        LOGGER.info("SQS Client Initialized Successfully");
        return new AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient(amazonSQSAsyncClient, config);
    }

@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    @Qualifier("workerSQS")
    public AmazonSQSAsync workerSQS() {
        final ClientConfiguration cc = new ClientConfiguration();
        cc.setConnectionTimeout(listenerConnectionTimeout);
        cc.setSocketTimeout(listenerSocketTimeout);
        cc.setMaxConnections(listenerMaxConnection);
        cc.setRequestTimeout(listenerRequestTimeout);
        cc.setUseReaper(true);
        //cc.setConnectionMaxIdleMillis();

        AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = new AWSCredentialsProvider() {
            public void refresh() {}
            public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
                return new AWSCredentials() {
                    public String getAWSSecretKey() {return routingSecretKey;}

                    public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {return routingAccessKey;}
                };
            }
        };

        AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsyncClient = AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                .withClientConfiguration(cc)
                .build();

        // See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-client-side-buffering-request-batching.html
        // for QueueBufferConfig Configuration Parameters
        QueueBufferConfig config = new QueueBufferConfig();
        config.setLongPoll(true);

        return new AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient(amazonSQSAsyncClient, config);
    }

 @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory msgListenerContainerFactory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
        msgListenerContainerFactory.setBackOffTime(listenerBackOffTime);
        msgListenerContainerFactory.setWaitTimeOut(listenerWaitTimeOut);
        msgListenerContainerFactory.setVisibilityTimeout(listenerVisibilityTimeOut);
        msgListenerContainerFactory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(listenerMaxMessagesPerPoll);
        msgListenerContainerFactory.setDestinationResolver(destinationResolver());
        return msgListenerContainerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomDestinationResolver destinationResolver(){
        return new CustomDestinationResolver();
    }

    @Component
    public static class CustomDestinationResolver implements DestinationResolver{

        @Autowired
        private AmazonSQS amazonSQS;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("workerSQS")
        private AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync;

        @Override
        public String resolveDestination(String name) throws DestinationResolutionException {
            String queueName = name;

            if (queueName.startsWith("tl")) {
                try {
                    GetQueueUrlResult getQueueUrlResult = amazonSQSAsync.getQueueUrl(new GetQueueUrlRequest(name));
                    return getQueueUrlResult.getQueueUrl();
                } catch (QueueDoesNotExistException var4) {
                    throw new DestinationResolutionException(var4.getMessage(), var4);
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    GetQueueUrlResult getQueueUrlResult = amazonSQS.getQueueUrl(new GetQueueUrlRequest(name));
                    return getQueueUrlResult.getQueueUrl();
                } catch (QueueDoesNotExistException var4) {
                    throw new DestinationResolutionException(var4.getMessage(), var4);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a spring autowiring issue - give them both specific qualifiers?. Nit - why go through the trouble of using the async buffered client instead of the normal client?

Comment: I dont know how to use the normal one... because SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory is using the Async client.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to do it with SQS Listener,so i tried with JMS listener and it worked. 
I simply created two JMS listenerContainerFactory and used them. Each listener have different AWS account